# Npm run dev not working and gives this error Error: > Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root

Tags: vite

I created a react project using vite. I am following a tutorial and when I tried running npm run dev this is the error I get Error: > Couldn't find any `pages` or `app` directory. Please create one under the project root.

I tried running npm run dev and expecting the local host to show me the website.